# Dictionary comparison with tuple as values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, python-3.6

I'm creating a simple dictionary comparison to search and match items. In this basic forms it works as expected.

```
def findOrders(lst, **kwargs):
    return [k for k in lst if kwargs.items() <= k.items()]

lst = [i for i in [ {'type':'esimene', 'id':1},
                    {'type':'teine', 'id':2},
                    {'type':'kolmas', 'id':3}]]

print(findOrders(lst, type='esimene'))
```

Now I would like to compare/match by multiple 'types' using a tuple as a keyword/values:

```
findOrders(lst, type=('esimene', 'teine'))
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Could I create a generator that flattens the tuple to 'type':'esimene' and 'type':'teine' and then runs the comparison? What would it look like?

Efficiency is also important this function will have heavy usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the the `type` parameter contains the `type` property of each item:

```py
In [8]: def findOrders(lst, **kwargs):
   ...:     return [k for k in lst if k["type"] in kwargs["type"]]

In [9]: print(findOrders(lst, type='esimene'))
[{'type': 'esimene', 'id': 1}]

In [10]: print(findOrders(lst, type=('esimene',  'teine')))
[{'type': 'esimene', 'id': 1}, {'type': 'teine', 'id': 2}]
```

If you want to keep the current logic with the `id` comparison as well:

```py
In [32]: def findOrders(lst, **kwargs):
    ...:     return [k for k in lst if k["type"] in kwargs.get("type", (k["type"], )) and k["id"] ==
    ...: kwargs.get("id", k["id"])]
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

In [33]: print(findOrders(lst, id=1))
[{'type': 'esimene', 'id': 1}]

In [34]: print(findOrders(lst, type=('esimene',  'teine')))
[{'type': 'esimene', 'id': 1}, {'type': 'teine', 'id': 2}]

In [35]: print(findOrders(lst, type=('esimene', 'teine'), id=2))
[{'type': 'teine', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, I am assuming OP is looking for a way to query the dictionary. i.e. `findOrders(lst, type='esimene')` or `findOrders(lst, type=('esimene',  'teine')` or  `findOrders(lst, id=1)`

Comment: @shahkalpesh Correct, that's exactly my goal. I'm trying to avoid doing findOrders(lst, type='esimene') or findOrders(lst, type='teine') or...it's ugly and inefficient.

Comment: Not quite following. What are you trying to achieve that my answer lacks?

Comment: I'd be matching on multiple keywords, so where type is any of the tuples and if id is supplied it also gets matched. So for example findOrders(lst, type=('esimene', 'teine'), id=2) would only return one match (with id=2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. Now I'm pondering if a Pandas version would be faster, the dictionary will be relatively small (less than a few hundred items) but it will receive queries at a high rate.

Comment: Should have mentioned there could be multiple tuples as keywords, I suspect using a list comprehension will then get unbearably complex.

Comment: I believe that's correct. I would advise you to try to implement it with Pandas - I do not have much experience with it, but maybe there's a builtin method to help you.

Comment: Although you could have a list with all possible keyword arguments, and then loop over it and check for the value. Shouldn't be that complex.